# Ошибка Python 3.6 TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Решил попробовать работу с VK API, нашел простой пример авторизации и запроса.

Пошел смотреть как парсить JSON, получился приблизительно такой код:

```
import vk, json
session = vk.Session(access_token='...')
api = vk.API(session)
findstr=api.users.search(q='Иван Иванов',sort=0,offset=0,count=10)
parsed_string = json.loads(findstr)
print(findstr)
```

Запустил, увидел такую ошибку

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: судя по всему api уже парсит json, поэтому не надо вызывать  `json.loads` дополнительно

Comment: Если пробовать вытащить напрямую: print(findstr['uid'][0]), то выводит уже другую ошибку TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @German а если так: `print(findstr[0]['uid'])`

Comment: @Alban Тогда `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @German точно, там же первый элемент это кол-во, попробуйте заменить 0 на 1

Comment: @Alban получилось, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

> parsed_string = json.loads(findstr)

У вас результат из findstr это список, а не объект JSON. Распечатайте список, проверьте содержимое. Если там есть JSON, то вы точно увидите его, так как он практически копия Python словаря типа {"Ключ": "Значение"} и как раз таки JSON  такого вида нужно декодировать. Возможно ваш findstr имеет вид [{"Ключ": "Значение"}], а значит нужно просто "вытащить" JSON объект оттуда и уже потом делать его json.loads(Извлеченный_Из_Списка_Объект).

Comment: если `search()` список возвращает, то вероятно содержимое уже преобразовано в Питон объекты (не нужно json.loads() явно вызывать)